# Corrupt playback of .flv when using JW Player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flv, jwplayer

This question is also asked on [Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/corrupt-video-when-playing-through-jw-player)

I have some files that when played in jwplayer the playback is corrupt.
The files are encoded to h.264 using FFMpeg and there is other files encoded in the same way that works.

At the moment we only use the flash version of the player.

This problem started showing up after we did an upgrade to FFMpeg, so I haven't ruled out that it could be an encoding error.

the command used to run FFMpeg is:

```
ffmpeg 
    -i /home/ftp/1c8f08b7d0d9e7fa4b24066156ad50bc981497a0.mov 
    -vcodec libx264 
    -preset ultrafast 
    -profile baseline 
    -acodec libfaac 
    -ab 96k 
    -crf 19 
    -vf movie="/home/adam/logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" 
    -y /home/ftp/1c8f08b7d0d9e7fa4b24066156ad50bc981497a0.flv
```

I am in no way an expert in FFMpeg commandline, so feel free to point out any mistakes made.

FFMpeg info:

```
ffmpeg version git-2012-05-02-2330eb1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  3 2012 08:51:25 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      51. 49.100 / 51. 49.100
  libavcodec     54. 17.101 / 54. 17.101
  libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 72.103 /  2. 72.103
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x24300e0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5187000
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/ftp/javarecorder/1c8f08b7d0d9e7fa4b24066156ad50bc981497a0.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2012-05-16 08:19:41
  Duration: 00:13:33.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2164 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24, 1366x768, 1457 kb/s, 8.43 fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-16 08:19:41
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-16 08:19:41
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Please use -profile:a or -profile:v, -profile is ambiguous
[buffer @ 0x2446ac0] w:1366 h:768 pixfmt:rgb24 tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[movie @ 0x242f840] seek_point:0 format_name:(null) file_name:/home/adam/logo.png stream_index:0
[overlay @ 0x2442840] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scale 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'Parsed_overlay_1'
[overlay @ 0x2442840] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scale 1' between the filter 'Parsed_movie_0' and the filter 'Parsed_overlay_1'
[scale @ 0x24444a0] w:1366 h:768 fmt:rgb24 sar:0/1 -> w:1366 h:768 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[scale @ 0x2445100] w:80 h:80 fmt:rgba sar:1/1 -> w:80 h:80 fmt:yuva420p sar:1/1 flags:0x4
[overlay @ 0x2442840] main w:1366 h:768 fmt:yuv420p overlay x:1276 y:678 w:80 h:80 fmt:yuva420p
[overlay @ 0x2442840] main_tb:1/1000000 overlay_tb:1/25 -> tb:1/1000000 exact:1
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] MB rate (4128000) > level limit (2073600)
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 5.2
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] 264 - core 124 r2197 69a0443 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=36 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=19.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
[libfaac @ 0x2443540] channel_layout not specified
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Output #0, flv, to '/home/ftp/javarecorder/1c8f08b7d0d9e7fa4b24066156ad50bc981497a0.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2012-05-16 08:19:41
    encoder         : Lavf54.3.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1366x768, q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-16 08:19:41
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-16 08:19:41
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (qtrle -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16be -> libfaac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:44100 fmt:s16 ch:1 chl:0x0 to rate:44100 fmt:s16 ch:1 chl:0x4
frame= 6856 fps=105 q=-1.0 Lsize=   36030kB time=00:13:32.83 bitrate= 363.1kbits/s
video:27775kB audio:7540kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.026555%
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] frame I:28    Avg QP: 4.61  size:238170
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] frame P:6828  Avg QP: 7.31  size:  3189
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.9%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  2.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:96.9%
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 32.3% 30.0% 29.0% inter: 1.0% 1.1% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 66% 32%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 62% 23% 14%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x242d8c0] kb/s:279.82
```

### EDIT:

A coworker was able to view a "corrupted" file. The only difference between my computer and his is that he have a Mac. Same flash version, same JW Player version. Something is not right here.

Comment: Please also provide the complete console output of your actual command. I'm guessing that your output pixel format may be something other than yuv420p, but it's impossible to tell without the console output.

Comment: Changed FFMpeg output to show a full run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the culprit was the framerate. Through some magic thing the framerate of the resulting video was around 1000. Using `-r 30` seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't put h.264 video into FLV containers.  It's not a good fit.  There could be all sorts of weirdness going on.  Use mp4 containers, where h264 is naturally at home.

Other suggestions/questions:

- drop or change the `crf` value, see if that makes a difference
- drop the overlay, does it make a difference?
- when you updated FFmpeg did you also update x264?
- drop the ultrafast preset, see if it makes a difference
- prefix baseline with v:, as is now required by FFmpeg sometime as of late 2011 (I think).

From your output:

```
Please use -profile:a or -profile:v, -profile is ambiguous
```

Comment: .flv is the important part as we show the video in browsers using flash, wich saves having to transcode into multiple formats. Losing the overlay dosn't seem to make any difference and We updated x264 as well.

Comment: Use f4v, which is basically just Adobe's subset of mp4.  There are serious issues with FLV and h264.  Flash has been playing mp4s for years now.

Comment: Seems like some videos is corrupted as mp4 :(

Comment: Sounds like your encoding is a problem if you event cannot get MP4s out of it.  Are you taking FFmpeg and h264 from nightly dumps?  If so then try again with a new/older version.  Some days the trunk is not as perfect as other days.  I would also strongly suggest dumping the `-preset ultrafast` stuff and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: OH!  I also see a warning in your output!  The baseline preset is considered ambiguous, so is ignored.  *(A while ago FFmpeg started requiring explicate `v` & `a` for certain parameters.)*

Comment: As you can see in my own answer, the issue seems to be the framerate. My guess is JWPlayer got "overloaded". I took your advice and will make more changes that just `-r 30`. Thanks!